# TypeError: RegistrationForm.validate_role() missing 1 required positional argument: 'pin'

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

I'm trying to restrict the ability to select a specific role when registering an account in a flask web application. I'm new to flask but I do have a good understanding of python. I'm not entirely sure why I am getting the above error, any help would be greatly appreciated!

*auth/forms.py*

```py
class RegistrationForm(FlaskForm):
    username = StringField('Username', validators=[DataRequired()])
    email = StringField('Email', validators=[DataRequired(), Email()])
    password = PasswordField('Password', validators=[DataRequired()])
    password2 = PasswordField(
        'Repeat Password', validators=[DataRequired(), EqualTo('password')])
    ### NOTICE: To get the label to show for the "Role" field using wtf.quickform
    ### you must edit flask-bootstrap/templates/wtf.html and add {{field.label(class="control-label")|safe}}
    ### BEFORE the for loop {% for item in field -%}
    ###                       <div class="radio">
    role = RadioField(label='Role',choices=['Department Head','Team Lead','Project Manager'],validators=[DataRequired()])
    pin = IntegerField(label='Access Code')
    submit = SubmitField('Register')

    def validate_username(self, username):
        user = User.query.filter_by(username=username.data).first()
        if user is not None:
            raise ValidationError('Please use a different username.')

    def validate_email(self, email):
        user = User.query.filter_by(email=email.data).first()
        if user is not None:
            raise ValidationError('Please use a different email address.')
        
    def validate_role(self,role,pin):
        roles = role.data
        pins = pin.data
        
        if pins != 1000 and roles == 'Department Head':
            raise ValidationError('This role requires the proper Access Code. Please contact Seymour Stats administration for access.')        
        elif pins != 2000 and roles == 'Team Lead':
            raise ValidationError('This role requires the proper Access Code. Please contact Seymour Stats administration for access.')
```

*auth/routes.py*

```py
@bp.route('/register', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register():
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect(url_for('main.index'))
    form = RegistrationForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user = User(username=form.username.data, email=form.email.data, role=form.role.data, pin=form.pin.data)
        user.set_password(form.password.data)
        db.session.add(user)
        db.session.commit()
        flash('Congratulations, you are now a registered user!')
        return redirect(url_for('auth.login'))
    return render_template('auth/register.html', title='Register', form=form)
```

*templates/auth/register.html*

```html
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% import 'bootstrap/wtf.html' as wtf %}

{% block app_content %}
<h1>Register</h1>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        {{ wtf.quick_form(form) }}
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

**ERROR MESSAGE:**
`TypeError: RegistrationForm.validate_role() missing 1 required positional argument: 'pin'`

Let me know if more of my code is required to get more detail. Thanks in advance!

## UPDATE

i was able to fix this issue by implementing the following code change in forms.py

```py
    def validate_role(self,pin):
        role = self.role.data
        pin = self.pin.data
        
        if pin != 1000 and role == 'Department Head':
            raise ValidationError('This role requires the proper Access Code. Please contact Seymour Stats administration for access.')        
        elif pin != 2000 and role == 'Team Lead':
            raise ValidationError('This role requires the proper Access Code. Please contact Seymour Stats administration for access.')
```

the issue now is that the `ValidationError` doesn't raise.